# Android GPS enable programmatically

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programmatically-like-tasker)

I want to get latitude and longitude programmatic in Android app. But it depended upon whether the GPS is enabled or not. I used to check the GPS with this code

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
{
    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) 
    { 
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

But it basically shows the screen to enable it. But I don't want that user should enable it. It should enable automatically if the gps is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, starting with Android 1.5. The most you can do is pop open the activity to allow the user to toggle it on/off.

Use the action held in android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS to craft an Intent to open this activity.

Comment: I m using 2.2 can i auto enable GPS in 2.2?

Comment: No, it's been disabled. It's a security feature. If the user doesn't want GPS, you don't get GPS. Period.

Comment: I think this post will help you http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186/make-certain-apps-turn-on-gps-automatically