# Is it possible to switch on GPS and Switch Off GPS programmatically?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)
>   [android GPS enable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139620/android-gps-enable-progrmmatically)

Need help to switch on GPS programmatically in certain interval of time.
Is it possible?

Comment: Congratulations, you have done a negative amount of research!

Comment: So some google before ask question

Comment: I have tried the snippets, but doesn't work with me. that's y asking the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet that can be used for this

```
 private void EnableGPS(){   

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);   
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){      
        final Intent poke = new Intent();  
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");           poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);   
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));      
        sendBroadcast(poke);  
   }  }
```

Comment: This has not worked in quite some time.

Comment: I have tried this code snippet, but it is not working...? how i can use in my app?