# Programmatically turn on/off GPS on Android

Tags: android, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

Is it possible to programmatically turn on/off gps on android? It is mentioned on this SO post: [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker) that it cannot be done without the user consent.

Comment: Take a look at these:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481695/how-to-enable-gps-in-android-coding

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715257/enabling-gps-programatically-in-android

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302894/ics-android-enable-gps-programmatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible. The closest you can get is firing an Intent that shows the GPS settings to the user. Please follow this guide: [Guide for GPS intent Android](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/calling-system-settings-android-app-gps-example)

Comment: it can actually be done by exploiting a certain loophole up to 2.2., but for others, see [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker – Richard Le Mesurier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker/5305835#5305835)