# how to programatically set GPS on/off in 4.0 and above

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing an app where I have a `Toggle Button` to turn on/off GPS. I went through this link [1st Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker) and also this [2nd Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944378/programmatically-turn-on-off-gps-on-android)

Since the answers are controversial I couldn't figure out. I use DU BATTERY SAVER and it has a widget where I can turn on/off GPS. The same feature I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to programatically set GPS on/off in 4.0 and above

This should not be possible, for privacy reasons.

> I use DU BATTERY SAVER and it has a widget where I can turn on/off GPS

Fortunately, they do not appear to have the feature that you describe, at least in the free edition for unrooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snipp

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code makes my phone to search for GPS satellites. I couldn't switch it off. I had to restart my phone