# Switch Android GPS programmatically

Tags: android, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programmatically-like-tasker)

I have searching on how to toggle GPS programmatically, the standard answer is that it's not possible.

If this is really the case how do all the various power/toggle related widgets manage to toggle GPS with one click and no warning. The market place is full of examples that show it is possible.

So how?

Comment: Can you name any app widgets on the Market that "toggle GPS with one click and no warning"?

Comment: Widgetsoid (Jaumard), PowerControl (Surius Apps), GPS OnOff (Curve Fish)... There are 3 straight off that I have tested and all work as I describe. Would you like me to list more there appears to be many more but I have not tested those yet

Comment: These are exploiting security holes in Android. Your prompt attention will help me in getting them fixed. Thanks!

Comment: This question comes up many times and there is an obvious demand for this functionality.

Would it not be better just to have a permission of ToggleGPS and let the user decide if they want to allow apps that have that sort of control over the GPS?

The current situation is just dumb

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on the emulator with 1.6 and it works.

[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

**EDIT:** This is not particularly allowed on the Android Market, and it stopped working as of android 2.3. I have also tested on a 2.1 emulator, and two actual devices with 2.2, and it worked on those.