# How to programatically disable/enable gps on rooted android?

Tags: android, gps, location, root, su

After rooting and requesting superuser permission what do I need to do to enable/disable gps in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't supposed to to protect the privacy of the user.  However it is possible by exploiting a bug.  See this for how:

[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

Note that this may not work on all versions of Android - see
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/4b21f7cd9424eeb83838071a4419912ee5d5e41d

where they indicate it has been fixed but i'm not sure which versions have the fix (if any).

Answer (score 2):

ON Rooted Device try this just use su for enabling gps on high accuracy mode

```
 Process proc=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su",
"pm grant com.your_app_packagename android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS",
"settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps,network,wifi"});
 proc.waitFor();
```

Run these command on background thread :)

further you can refer to this link [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40147/is-it-possible-to-enable-location-services-via-shell/114033#114033?s=7eb820622b1448118ffbcf373b489cc5)

Answer (score 1):

This code works on **ROOTED** phones **if the app is moved to** `/system/aps`, **and they have the following permissions in the manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

**Code**

```
private void turnGpsOn (Context context) {
    beforeEnable = Settings.Secure.getString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                              Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    String newSet = String.format ("%s,%s",
                                   beforeEnable,
                                   LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    try {
        Settings.Secure.putString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                   Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED,
                                   newSet); 
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}


private void turnGpsOff (Context context) {
    if (null == beforeEnable) {
        String str = Settings.Secure.getString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (null == str) {
            str = "";
        } else {                
            String[] list = str.split (",");
            str = "";
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                if (!list[i].equals (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    if (j > 0) {
                        str += ",";
                    }
                    str += list[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            beforeEnable = str;
        }
    }
    try {
        Settings.Secure.putString (context.getContentResolver(),
                                   Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED,
                                   beforeEnable);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}
```