# Switch off GPS programmatically

Tags: android, gps

**What i have:**  Currently my app is giving location through gps.

**what i want:** Gps to turn off automatically after i exit from the application. Because it keeps on telling me the location time and again that looks odd and also gps consume a lot battery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker

Comment: well i must try it. . .Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at above comment thread it seems its possible to turn OFF GPS programatically (But seeing only 12 Upvotes)

**But if you switch OFF GPS from your application programatically, what if other applications use GPS Service ?**

The ***solution*** would be like

Open `Settings` of android and then tell user to turn OFF GPS when he exits from the application...

For this you can do like :

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

**OR**

You can try like

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener); 
locationManager = null;
```

This shutdown gps for this app, but its still available for use by other apps.

Comment: It is posssible still now.See the commented post.

Comment: It is possible,But I didn't find any thing to believe the existing of the possibility in future

Comment: @Rasel....  LocationManager.removeUpdates(Listener);  is the answer to my question..as it only turns off gps for my app.

Answer (score 2):

This code can alter your gps.But it is not documented

```
 final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though the link Rasel posted contains some code which might work you should keep in mind that the code is exploiting a security flaw which has been fixed already (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7890) and therefore shouldn't work in the near future anymore.

Comment: so u mean i should not use it??

Comment: @Noman: Depends what you are trying to do. If it's for personal use, go ahead. If you want to distribute your application I wouldn't use it because it's not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable the GPS programmaticaly  then copy and paste this code in your project, its working fine.

```
      final Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
      i.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
       sendBroadcast(i); //if you are in broad cast receiver activity then use context.sendBroadcast(i)
```

Comment: Appears to not be working for me now, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: **This** solution and the one above by **Rasel** will only work up to Android 2.3.6 - not v3.x.x or v4.x.x - although there are some suggestions that this _vulnerability_ has been re-introduced in Android 4.1.2 and it may work yet again!

Comment: @Chuong thanks for informing and putting a comment. its helpful