# Overriding GPS Enabling Prompt

Tags: android, permissions, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

I'm trying to write an app that's used for transmitting GPS coordinates in an emergency. Is there a way to enable the GPS without requiring user input (I'd like to avoid as much user interaction as possible)

Answer (score 1):

No, Then any app would be able to start your GPS without your consent.

Comment: So there's no way to explicitly give a single app the permission initially to always enable the GPS without further user consent?

Comment: Not that I am aware of... the only option I can think of would be to require the user to have GPS enabled all the time.

Comment: Hm all right, thanks. If I find some workaround, ill repost here.

Comment: **This is Possible .Check this**        [link]            (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

Comment: Considering that the accepted answer is an exploited bug, I would not trust using it, especially for future Android releases.

Comment: This answer is long outdated now