# Turn on GPS inside the code

Tags: android, gps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

I would like to know how to turn on the GPS inside the code ?
someone says you cannot and other says you can, I get confused 
Pleas help me,

Comment: I presume that what you mean is "enable GPS". Turning it on is simply a matter of using some `LocationManager` method to ask for GPS fixes (e.g., `requestLocationUpdates()`), which only works if GPS is enabled. All known security flaws that other people were suggesting to enable GPS are now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Turning the GPS on requires user interaction as a security measure.  If any application were able to turn the GPS on without the user knowing, that would be a very big privacy concern.

You can launch an Intent that takes the user to the GPS screen to turn it on / off.

`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));`

Comment: Wrong activity action, I think -- `ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`

Comment: I asked myself the same thing a couple of months ago, but then realized it would be a HUGE privacy concern for me to enable GPS without user interaction.

Comment: I'd been sending my app to that system config screen with 'new intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS)', as per the original answer. ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS seems to send it to the same screen (at least on the emulator it does) - I'm wondering what the difference is?

Comment: **This is possible. Check this**  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)