# android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

Hello my problem is that when I try to change weather or not the GPS setting is enabled I get the following error `10-20 05:44:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(889): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` while in my manifest file I do have the permission listed in the error inside my manifest file.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you ever solved this issue? I'm experiencing it now. My application is in /system/app and still throwing this exception

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro Yes I have, did you look at the answer below?

Comment: Yes, my app installed in /system/app, therefore it should be a system app and able to get that permission. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MiguelRibeiro In order for that to work you need to put the source code of your app within the source of android itself then compile android from source. Then your app will have a system signature. But I wouldn't recommend it because its a breach of trust between you and the user and a security issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` is a `signatureOrSystem` permission, meaning that ordinary SDK applications cannot hold it. Only apps that are related to the firmware can hold this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Reading all answers for this particular issue, one way around for this is to use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004614/398802) to enable the gps but it wont work, as CommonsWare pointed, the application has to be system app for getting this code to work..so one can convert the application into system app by using TitaniumBackup. THis is working perfectly fine for me now.

*Sony users will see another message "Will collect anonymous data while using gps" - to overcome this, 'Freeze' the "LEarning Client" app and everything will be fine.

Comment: good point. With htc sense they haven't patched a bug in the system power widget that lets you toggle the gps with a warning dialog that pops up. Thus letting the user confirm what your trying to do.