# Can't modify Settings.Secure database in a 3rd app

Tags: android

I want to modify something in Settings.secure database, just as the android Settings app do:

```
Settings.Secure.putString(
        getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.VOICE_RECOGNITION_SERVICE,
        setting);
```

I have added following permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Unfortunately, the app aborts saying:

> E/DatabaseUtils(  147): Writing exception to parcel E/DatabaseUtils( 
>   147): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to
>   secure settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
>   E/DatabaseUtils(  147):         at
>   com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.checkWritePermissions(SettingsProvider.java:211)
>   E/DatabaseUtils(  147):         at
>   com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insert(SettingsProvider.java:552)
>   E/DatabaseUtils(  147):         at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:198)
>   E/DatabaseUtils(  147):         at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
>   E/DatabaseUtils(  147):         at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320) E/DatabaseUtils( 
>   147):         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

If I sign this app with the platform key it would be OK, but for different systems, the platform key seems different. It can't be run on other devices.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Seems like you need to look at the android source and see why you are getting denied.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862812/android-permission-write-secure-settings-error). This permission can be granted to properly signed applications or to the applications located at system image (`/system/app`) only.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did noticed that in frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my own question:

In frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml, WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS is declared with protectionLevel signatureOrSystem. So it's impossible for a normal app to obtain this permission, unless it's put in system image, or signed with the same key used by framework res apk.