# I am facing issue in clear Default browsers on button click

Tags: android

Hi Guys i m making web browser and i m facing some problem i m making my browser default but when i wants to clear default browser if any other browser is default then it will show security exception i m using this `getActivity().getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(currentHomePackage);`
with the help of this i can clear own package only but not other default browser package
i want clear default browser just on button click i don't want to open setting from program anyone help me Guys

```
packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        resolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        currentHomePackage = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(Constants.DefaultURL);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setData(uri);

   if (switchButton.isChecked()) {

                if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase(getActivity().getPackageName()) || resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {
                   /* SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Constants.DefaultBrowserSetting, true);
                    editor.commit();*/
                    Log.d("ppp checked", "--" + currentHomePackage);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {

getActivity().getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(currentHomePackage);
                }
            } else {
                packageManager.clearPackagePreferredActivities(getActivity().getPackageName());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.DefaultBrowserSetting, false);
                editor.commit();
                switchButton.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SecurityException means you are missing some permissionsin your manifest file. give the required permission. you can search more on google about 
permissions in android.

Comment: i have already use this permission in manifest this show error says this permission use only for System apps java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10276 nor current process has android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352472/android-java-lang-securityexception-for-system-app/32219895