# ON the GPS connectivity through Phonegap application

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm working on a phonegap application for track the geolocation of the
user. i was able to get the gps locations correctly.
but for get that location ,I should ON the GPS connectivity in my
phone, before my app launch. Is there any way to ON the GPS
connectivity inside my application.

Thanks.

Comment: No. I think you can just prompt the user to do it themselves.

Comment: Check these:http://stackoverflow.com/q/1051649/190695 http://stackoverflow.com/q/4721449/190695 http://stackoverflow.com/q/8600731/190695