# Android GPS Enable. Not working?

Tags: android, gps, manifest

I didn't find idea Where is the problem?
should I write something into Manifest to enable this functionality?

```
private void toggleGPS(boolean enable) {
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 
        Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider.contains("gps") == enable) {
    return; // the GPS is already in the requested state
}

final Intent poke = new Intent();
poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
context.sendBroadcast(poke);
```

}`

Comment: Do you have GPS access enabled in the Manifest ?

Comment: read this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker

Comment: @user1197305:what permissions you are using in Manifest??

Comment: @ all ..I didn't write any permission into Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to give permission in manifest.xml of  `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 0):

There are different permissions you might add in your Android Manifest.xml for location you might want the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Read the [manifest permission documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for more details