# How to ask user to enable GPS at the launch of application?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
}
}
```

see the Logcat

```
04/20 17:35:26: Launching app
$ adb push F:\AndroidProject\Picker\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "picker.novasyslabs.com.picker/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SlashScreen" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 22502 on device sony-d2302-ZH80065A89
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 151(19KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 13MB/22MB, paused 5.156ms total 20.919ms
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: picker.novasyslabs.com.picker, PID: 22502
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{picker.novasyslabs.com.picker/picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SlashScreen}: java.lang.ClassCastException: picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SlashScreen cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SlashScreen cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks
                      at picker.novasyslabs.com.picker.SlashScreen.onCreate(SlashScreen.java:65)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740) 
Application terminated.
```

I tried many other option like package manager, location manager, etc but not able to do what I want.
        I want that at the launch application user will be prompted to enable the GPS.
    I don't want user to go inside the settings.

And that I wanted for the API level >=19.

Please help me to solve my problem.........
Thanks

Comment: If you are willing to use Google Play Services, `SettingsApi` has some options for prompting the user to enable locations. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Location/FusedPeriodic) demonstrates the technique. Otherwise, what you want is not possible.

Comment: use this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps>

Comment: Thanks this works for me. Thank u so much. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show enable location dialog like Google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801368/how-to-show-enable-location-dialog-like-google-maps)

Answer (score 27):

If you want something as shown in below image, follow along.

[image: Permission for GPS]

1. Add the following dependencies in your app `build.gradle`

   ```
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
   ```
2. Create the type of location request you want, we want high accuracy for GPS

   ```
     LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
     locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
     LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                   .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
   ```
3. Now we need to check current state of GPS. For this, we have to use `LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build())` This will return a `Task` which needs to handled asynchronously. In RESOLUTION_REQUIRED case, we ask user to give permissions, this is where we show the user prompt to enable GPS.

   ```
   Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
                   LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());



   result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                   try {
                       LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                       // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                       // requests here.
                   } catch (ApiException exception) {
                       switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                           case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                               // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                               // user a dialog.
                               try {
                                   // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                   ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                   // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                   // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                   resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                           getActivity(),
                                           LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                               } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                   // Ignore the error.
                               } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                                   // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                               }
                               break;
                           case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                               // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                               // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                               break;
                       }
                   }
               }
           });
   ```
4. Now that we have asked user to turn on GPS, we need to check whether user allowed it or ignored it. For this, override onActivityResult. Please note that, if you're implementing above code in a fragment, result will be received in the enclosing Activity. So override onActivityResult in the Activity class.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   switch (requestCode) {
       case LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY:
           switch (resultCode) {
               case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                   // All required changes were successfully made
                   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: GPS Enabled by user");
                   break;
               case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                   // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                   Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult: User rejected GPS request");
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }
           break;
       } 
   }
   ```

[From Android Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient)

Answer (score 11):

This is the kotlin implementation of @Ananth answer

```
private fun showLocationPrompt() {
        val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest)

        val result: Task<LocationSettingsResponse> = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(activity).checkLocationSettings(builder.build())

        result.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            try {
                val response = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.
            } catch (exception: ApiException) {
                when (exception.statusCode) {
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED -> {
                        try {
                            // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                            val resolvable: ResolvableApiException = exception as ResolvableApiException
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                activity, LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
                            )
                        } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
                            // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        }
                    }
                    LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE -> {
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                        // user a dialog.

                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY -> {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.e("Status: ","On")
                } else {
                    Log.e("Status: ","Off")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use SettingsApi if you not want to force user to go settings page to enable gps. 
here the link of how to use SettingsApi
[SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi)

Comment: This has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void showSettingAlert()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS setting!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled, Do you want to go to settings menu? ");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Setting", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: The question has 'I don't want user to go inside the settings."

Comment: No, final decision rely on user either GPS on or off

Comment: you prompt this dialog until GPS on

Answer (score 0):

[Image of GPS permission like Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izz03.jpg)

If you want to ask permission like shown in the above link, you can refer to my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757407/10618364

Code is written with **GoogleApi** and **SettingsClient** API, not with deprecated *GoogleClientApi* and *SettingsApi*.

It is also compatible with Android 11. ;)