# Android BLE onScanResult is never called

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have developed a little BLE App for Android which connects with my mobile music Box.
Everything works fine on my phone (Android 9). So I bought a tablet (Android 9) and there onScanResult is never called, but when I search with Android board-function I see the Bluetooth device.

```
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
BLUETOOTH 
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

is set and Location is set to on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your bluetooth is on then give runtime permission of , ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and  ACCESS_CORSE_LOCATION and still you are facing this issue then gps on and restart scanning its working fine.

Required permission for BLE,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
   <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

and check gps is enable or not

```
       private fun enableLocation(): Boolean {
    val service = activity?.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as   LocationManager
    val enabled = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    return enabled
}
```

and if return false then

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                    startActivity(intent)
```

for enable your gps progrmatically and if true then scan your device.

Comment: You are right. isProviderEnabled shows false. But where can I turn it on. The Location is on and with your method Action_Location_Source_Settings I don't get to the GPS and Location is already enabled.

Comment: ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS is used for go to your gps setting page.. enable it and restart process again.

Comment: I have on this page only one menu point and this is Location and it's set to on. Should I have another button or menupoint for GPS?

Comment: no on click of check if(enableLocation())  if it is true scan your device else you can show a dialog for enable gps permission if it press ok call intent  with ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928256/how-to-turn-on-the-gps-on-android

Comment: Many thanks for your Answers. I have found my Problem. You cannot check for GPS. Then you get Always false. When you delete isProviderEnabled(GPS_Provider) then it works correctly… That is very strange, but it is like it is!

Comment: alright but its working fine for my side in all condition and i have check every time for status of gps before scanning.if you are facing any issue regarding BLE then tell me.

Answer (score 0):

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION could be declared in manifest but it's not treated as granted by default. Have you requested for granting this permission in runtime? If not, request for it in runtime or just go to permissions section in your app settings and grant it manually.

Comment: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is permitted and the app has also the permission