# Android this app turns GPS on and off

Tags: android, gps, return

I recently saw this app on the Google Play

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidlost&hl=fr

I was particularly interested to know how does it do that kind of stuff ?? (knowing that for security reasons you can't do it with the Android SDK normally...)

```
* start/stop GPS
* start/stop WIFI
```

Is there any kind of trick to allow this to be possible ?

Thank you

Comment: This is fully supported by the sdk

Answer (score 1):

for Enable/Disable GPS programatically see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)  and for Wifi :

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
final Intent poke = new Intent();
poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
 poke.setData(Uri.parse("0")); 
int wifistatus = ((WifiManager)con.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).getWifiState();
if(wifistatus==1)  //if WIFI is disabled
{
sendBroadcast(poke);
}
else //if WIFI is enable
{
sendBroadcast(poke);
}
```

manifest.xml permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```