# how to hide the gps icon on status bar when the service stops?

Tags: android

I need to hide the GPS icon from the status bar when my service disabled.

In my application I have two menu options, when I press the "enable" then the gps icon has to display on status bar and when I press the "disable" then the gps icon should not display on the status bar.

Comment: Thank u. Already I did this but I don't want to disable the gps through settings.I want to disable it through programming when I press the "disable" menu item.

Comment: If what you're asking is how to hide the GPS icon when GPS is actually still active, then no -- you can't do that. Nor should you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are requesting for GPS updates through the `LocationManager`, you can use this function to remove the updates (disable GPS):

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the GPS icon when service is stop you need to remove registration for location updates of the current activity.

You can do this by calling the `removeUpdates(PendingIntent intent)` on location manager.

```
removeUpdates(PendingIntent intent)
Removes any current registration for location updates of the current activity with the given PendingIntent.
```

check out this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you gonna have to disable the GPS device. When you disable GPS, icon will dissapear from the system tray.

[Check this question for the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker)

Comment: Can I write the code like this in service class's onDestroy method

Comment: like public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
    mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    ((LocationManager) mlocListener).removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);
   Log.v("destroy","destroy");
 
  
   Intent it=new Intent(NewThread.this,LanLatActivity.class);
   startActivity(it);
   flag=false;
   
  }

Comment: to stop GPS and show the home page of application( LanLatActivity). Here the application terminates when I click "Disable" menu item. Pls help me. Its some urgent task for me.

Comment: In another way also I tried. the below code                              public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();                     ((LocationManager) mlocListener).removeUpdates((LocationListener) this); flag=false;

Answer (score 0):

Simple. When you want the icon, enable GPS, and when you don't want it, disable GPS.

Comment: thank you very much. If I have any doubt I will ask u because I am new to this technology. I am working on this from 2 weeks.