# How to enable and disable GPS(on button click) without going to GPS settings page

Tags: android, button, gps

With a button click how can we enable and disable GPS programmatically.

When we click the button for the first time we should enable the GPS , on second click on the same button we should disable the GPS

I searched for the related threads but I didn't find any solution

Please share some related links/code

Any help is always appreciated, Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With a button click how can we enable and disable GPS programmatically.

Fortunately, you can't anymore, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I saw the same functionality in LG mobile. I thought of doing that.

Comment: Is it possible in any other way?I mean navigating to GPS  settings page

Comment: @Raghav: You can navigate the user to the Location page in the Settings app, at least on most devices. `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))` should do it.

Comment: @CommonsWare quite old answer, I saw a few days back google maps is doing this on a button click. Any idea how they are doing it?

Comment: @Akram: If you are using Google Play Services, they have a largely-undocumented `SettingsApi` that appears to be how you do this: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi.html