# Internet permission in Android app not granted

Tags: android, acra, android-permissions

I'm trying to use [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) in my project but whenever my app launches, I see the following message in the log.

```
E/ACRA    (11618): com.example.TestApp should be granted permission android.permission.INTERNET if you want your crash reports to be sent. If you don't want to add this permission to your application you can also enable sending reports by email. If this is your will then provide your email address in @ReportsCrashes(mailTo="your.account@domain.com"
```

Below is my `AndroidManifest.xml`, which has Internet permissions, so not sure what's going on here. Any help appreciated!

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.TestApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="TestApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity_"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: When you looked at the ACRA source code to see where they are logging this, what did you find?

Comment: @CommonsWare It's a pretty straightforward permissions check using `PackageManager`. I don't think this issue is really related to ACRA.

Comment: Try moving `<uses-permission>` before `<application>` (e.g., after `<uses-sdk>`). The packaging tools can kinda get picky about where these elements go, and that's where I usually see it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had already tried that as I found the same info elsewhere. Didn't help.

Comment: @jagsler Yup. Tried that and made sure to completely remove from the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I ran on JellyBean, since the READ_LOGS permission was removed in JB.

See this question for how to work around this problem in API 16 and above:
[READ_LOGS permission on Jelly Bean (api 16)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16)