# Foreground thread that reads from logcat is paused in Android ICS

Tags: android, multithreading, service, logcat, foreground

I have an application that starts a thread in background. This thread read the logcat:

```
public class MonitorLogService extends Service{

...

    private void handleCommand(Intent intent){
    if (ACTION_FOREGROUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.app_name);

        // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify, text, System.currentTimeMillis());

        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class), 0);

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, text,getText(R.string.service_running), contentIntent);
        startForegroundCompat(R.string.service_running, notification);

        monitorLogThread = new MonitorLogThread();
        monitorLogThread.start();
    }
}

private static Thread monitorLogThread;

private class MonitorLogThread extends Thread{

    BufferedReader br; 

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {   

                Process process;
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -b events");
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line;

                // Lee mientras no haya líneas nulas o el proceso se interrumpa
                while(((line=br.readLine()) != null) && !this.isInterrupted()){
                    Log.d("MyApp",line);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine in Android 2.3 but I have a problem in Android 4: **"br.readLine()"** doesn't return any line when I leave the app, it's just paused. When I open again the application, the service return the logcat lines.

I don't understand what happend because in Android 2.3 everything works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the API 16 doesn't support the logs reading permission [as I found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16)

Answer (score 0):

The command `logcat -b events` dump the buffer, but stills attached to the buffer waiting additional events and will never exit.

To have `logcat` exiting after reading the information in the buffer, you need to add the flag `-d`.

Example:

```
logcat -d -b events
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Luis but attach the buffer waiting for additional events and never exit is precisely what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it. I've tried you code in a test app (SDK 16), added uses permission `READ_LOGS`, and service in `START_STICKY` mode and it runs fine. Keeps logging events, even after exiting activity. The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: I use permission READ_LOGS and service START_STICKY as it's done in the samples demo file "ForegroundService.java" from the sdk documentation. I edited my question and you can see how i call the thread. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the API 16 doesn't support the logs reading permission as I found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16

Comment: You are correct. I've done the test above in emulator, and it seems only to affect real devices.