# Android, Logcat and BufferedReader - no logs

Tags: java, android, logging, logcat

I'm making an application, which must show me in logs which applications I start on device. I use `logcat ActivityManager:I *:S` and it doing this well.. at some devices and emulators.

But at some devices it has strange behavior - everything I see in log is repetition of:

`02-18 16:32:09.132: D/LockApp(4082): --------- beginning of /dev/log/main`

Code snippet:

```
Process process = null;
try {
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
    process = null;
    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat ActivityManager:I *:S");
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = null;

    line = br.readLine();

    while( line != null && !this.isInterrupted()){
        Log.d(Tag, "Start LockApp loop");
        Log.d(Tag, line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.d(Tag, e.toString());
}
```

And I have `android.permission.READ_LOGS` in Manifest

I`m doing it in Android 4.1 and 4.2

Comment: Which device you failed on?

Comment: You only call br.readLine() once. The buffer might be full, keep reading it.

Comment: It fails at Asus Tf300 and u30gt-h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is this `logcat -c`> this will Clears (flushes) the entire log and exits.

There are only `V,D,I,W,E & WTF` :-) Six type of logcat category

change it to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -e");`
[Link here:](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

**EDIT:**
There is an problem in Reading in jelly bean 
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11461650/1012284)

READ_LOGS permission on Jelly Beans (Android 4.1) will not be granted anymore to normal apps.

Apps are only allow to read their own logs.

See for more [information](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e94e00e62ad66a78)

You could try to implement a function to grant yourself READ_LOGS permission with for users with rooted devices.

Comment: -c: Clears (flushes) the entire log and exits

Comment: see [log filtering](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)

Comment: @padma-kumar, when i comment logcat -c it also doesn`t work. And there aren't -e option.

Comment: But my app work perfectly with Jelly Bean, and does not with some 4.1 devices.