# Is there a way to catch Web console errors?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Using WebView, certain websites take **very long time** to complete page load (as in [WebViewClient.onPageFinished()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)) and, when that happens, this is characterize by Web Console errors of the following type:

```
E/Web Console(1916): Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
  http://mobile.example.com from frame with URL 
  http://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/interactive.example.com/front_sub;sz=320x50;ord=7340930261983.
  Domains, protocols and ports must match.
  05-26 10:44:15.274: E/Web Console(1916):  at null:1
```

I would like to be able to catch those errors and handle them in some way. e.g. issue a message or anything relevant to my app, actual handling is irrelevant at this point to the core question:

Is there a way to catch those errors? i.e. in a way that my app can be notified?

**Note:** This is not a Javascript question. I am not programming a website. I am accessing an *existing* website whose implementation is beyond my control. This is a [WebView](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) question (currently in the Android environment, but could be in other environments which are capable of hosting WebView as well).

Comment: **Note:** This is not a WebView question. This is a "How do I read logs?" question.

Comment: A quick search yeilds [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16). I am afraid, you are out of luck with this.

Comment: I don't think OP wants to read the logs, I think he wants to catch the error that generated the log message, and handle it himself.

Comment: @shoerat Reading logs of other apps (or even system logs) is a horse of different color: (1) This type of log **is** received in the context of my app. (2) I hope that I don't need to intercept log messages in order to know about this event. I am hoping for some type of exception thrown or onReceivedError() notification, similar to the one that occurs on SSL errors. Is that possible?

Comment: AFAIK there is no notification for that. The best you can do is to monitor LogCat using AsyncTask following the example code in [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12692103) or even better [this open-source app](http://code.google.com/p/android-logger/). Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have an example of a website?

You should be able to override `WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage).`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this example provided by google for [Debugging Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html)

Notice that only "part1" is shown when you provide a comma delimited list of paramters within the `console.log` function, here is a piece of javascript code to test that:

```
console.log("part1","part2");
```

The result will be:

```
part1 -- From line 1 of http://example.js10/test.js
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kristian posted here we can do like below,

```
 final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // make sure JS enabled as true

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        Log.d(getClass().toString(), consoleMessage.message() + " -- From line "
                + consoleMessage.lineNumber() + " of "
                + consoleMessage.sourceId());
        return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
    }
});

webView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.url_google));
```