# Why I can 't get android radio log with Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -b radio -v time -s GSM");

Tags: android, logging, logcat

As title, I can get orhter log   ex.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d|);
try {

            Log.e("test", "1");
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "logcat -b radio -v time -s GSM");
            Log.e("test", "2");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
            Log.e("test", "3");
            String line;
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

            if (reader.readLine() != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                    line = reader.readLine();
                    list.add(line);
                }
            }
            Log.e("test", "4");
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Log.e("a123456", list.get(i).toString());
            }
        } catch (Exception t) {
            Log.e("test", "5");
            Log.e("test", t.getMessage());
        }
```

test log 1 2 3
can be print . but can't get any Exception log.I think it must be block
why?
ps: I use Sony phone jelly bean eng

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue too. Based on my research it's most likely due to Jellybean no longer allowing any 3rd party app to view logcat logs except for its own, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang).