# How to get System Logs form 4.3 android OS

Tags: android

I am trying to get the system log from 4.3 android version, but not getting anything.
My app functionality is depended on system log and I am using commandLine.add("logcat") to get it. If anybody has solution please suggest ?

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @user2481833 post your code

Comment: commandLine.add("logcat");
commandLine.add("-v");
commandLine.add("time");
commandLine.add("-b");
commandLine.add("events");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16), it's no longer supported on unrooted devices starting with Jelly Bean. So you have to root your device and run the command as `root` for it to work. Code examples are available [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16).

Comment: Thanks for replying.
 But is there any way I can make it working on non-rooted device? Because ultimately end –user will get non-rooted device.
How can I use below command programmatically?

"adb shell pm grant <pkg.name> android.permission.READ_LOGS"

Comment: No, you can't according to that.