# how to import com.android.camera package in a java project

Tags: java, android

Hi I am writing a test using UIAutomator API , however in my java project I want to import the com.android.camera package.
However I am always getting an error that this import cannot be resolved.
I have added the android.jar in my build path and rest of the things work fine.
However I am not able to import this package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such package in android, maybe you are looking for

> com.android.hardware.Camera

class ?

if so try

```
import com.android.hardware.Camera;
```

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve the values of the variable

mShutterToPostViewCallbackTime , mPictureDisplayedToJpegCallbackTime ,mJpegCallbackFinishTime which are from the class CameraActivity.
But I am doing this in a UIAutomator class

Comment: CamearaActivity is part of Android Camera App, you can't do unit testing for 3rd party apps since you don't have access to their source code. try building your test with a different approach instead

Comment: Is there a way to read the values of these from logcat within my UiAutomator class?

Comment: unless the android device you're testing on is rooted I don't think that is possible, also I don't think that those values are being logged in the first place. do you see them in the logcat ?

Comment: Yes its rooted, I do see them in logcat, the logging level is V and TAG is "SomeTest". How can I read these values?                                    
V/CAM_TEST MODULE(2014) :  mShutterToRawCallbackTime = xxxxxxxxms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16/12642918#12642918

check this

Answer (score 0):

The camera class resides inside the below package so try to import below package instead of `com.android.camera`  add the below.

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

Answer (score 0):

> import android.hardware.Camera;

try to place it after your package name

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse than just press **Ctrl + Shift + O** Eclipse will automatically add the required libraries in your source code. If still you are getting import issue than you need to check if you are using correct API or the spelling is correct.