# Which permissions can be granted to rooted devices?

Tags: android, adb, root, android-permissions

Short and simple question:

rooted devices can grant apps with extra permissions during runtime (using "grant permission" command using the adb , as I recall). An example for this is the ability to read system logs , which became a non-user permission starting with API16 (link [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16)) .

Is there a list of such permissions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command you may be thinking of is `pm grant PACKAGE PERMISSION`, which can be sent to an adb-connected device using `adb shell pm grant PACKAGE PERMISSION`.

However, only optional permissions can be granted or revoked this way. If you try to grant a permission not requested in the app's manifest, you'll get `Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Package PACKAGE has not requested permission PERMISSION`. Likewise, if you try to revoke a permission not deemed optional, you'll get `Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't change PERMISSION. It is required by the application`. Even for a rooted device or emulator.

Now, as far as what is deemed 'optional', as well as getting a list of such permissions, that's a little unclear. However, based on some experimentation, I believe these include at least the set of permissions assigned to permission group `android.permission-group.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS`. You can see which these are on a running device using `pm list permissions -g`.  On my API 19 emulator, as well as a Nexus 7 running AOSP 4.4.4, these are:

```
group:android.permission-group.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS
  permission:android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  permission:android.permission.SIGNAL_PERSISTENT_PROCESSES
  permission:android.permission.READ_LOGS
  permission:android.permission.SET_ALWAYS_FINISH
  permission:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
  permission:android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT
  permission:android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
  permission:android.permission.DUMP
  permission:android.permission.SET_DEBUG_AP
```

If (and only if) these are declared in the manifest, then you can grant/revoke them using the above command. Note that they are not granted automatically on installation; you must issue the `pm grant` command. I was able to observe and confirm this by using the Settings app and seeing the reported permissions change as I granted and revoked them.

There may be other permissions that behave like this, but I haven't found them. Normal permissions like `android.permission.INTERNET` cannot be granted or revoked in this manner.

Addendum: Per additional question in comment section regarding `pm set-permission-enforced PERMISSION`: As far as I know, the only permission which currently supports this is `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I'm basing this statement on my reading of the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#11584), which is also consistent with my experiences using the command. The purpose of the selective enforcement setting on this permission is to allow testing of apps under pre- and post-API 19 conditions as described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

Comment: Interesting. What should I look for in the output of the command ?

Comment: Thank you. so it seems that blocking permissions isn't allowed. What is "set-permission-enforced" used for (found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm ) ?

Comment: This sounds weird. "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" wasn't enforced, so for me it sounds as if it was completely useless before API 19... Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Only permission with the "development" flag can be granted, that's all permissions in the android.permission-group.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS group except the most useful one; android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Is there a Java/kotlin snippet that I can use to list all of those permissions that can only be granted via root/adb? Also, seems on Q listing all permissions by groups doesn't work well, as it doesn't show the `DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS` group, it's missing some of the permissions you've mentioned, and it doesn't put many permissions into their correct groups: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138239135 . That's by using either adb or the framework...