# How can a system app read the entire logcat programmatically in CyanogenMod 11?

Tags: java, android, logcat, android-permissions, cyanogenmod

I'm writing an app to include in a custom CyanogenMod build that needs to access the full logcat. I've tried the following:

```
...getRuntime().exec("su -c logcat -c");
```

but not getting anything from the input stream. I also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642918), and `su` exited with code 0, but it goes through the whole permission thing every time I run the app (when it should only need to do it once), and the code after it (a regular `exec("logcat")`, without worrying about permissions, which previously was pulling up the app's logs successfully) is no longer working (not getting any content).

My app is in /system/app, which some comments I saw led me to believe could get me the READ_LOGS permission in an easier way *somehow*, but I don't know how and am having trouble finding out. (I did try just adding the permission to my manifest, which didn't change the log content I was getting.)

(Also possibly worth noting that I'm working on a Nexus 7.)

Comment: You could take a look at [CatLog](https://github.com/nolanlawson/Catlog).

Comment: Do you mean `logcat -C` (color output)?  logcat -c just clears the log and exits.