# How to check the number of time the user open camera in android

Tags: android, camera, gps

I want to check the interaction between user and the resources of each application can access. in other word, is there a way I can check how many times the GPS is enabled, disabled, and the same for other system resources such as camera , wifi, and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: This must be a custom ROM or a sideloaded service with root privileges.

Comment: Thanks for replying, what about if i want to know what are the resources the application are using while it is running. for example I know that android os will check the permissions from the manifest file then will give the privilege to the app at the installation time, but if the user install snapchat for example and he never use the gps can I know that?

Comment: Please define *you* in this question: some system monitor, running with root access to [**/proc**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)? some analytics service, built into the app? a 3rd party app that does not have special permissions?

Comment: I'm working to build an app and i want to find a way that i can monitor other applications settings, I want to know which settings the user enabled and disabled in each app

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible, In fact, apps like [Quality Time](http://www.qualitytimeapp.com) and 'App Lockers' rely on it.
The way I think they might be doing this is by analyzing  `logcat`'s output.

You can do this by adding a permission `android.permission.READ_LOGS` and then acting accordingly in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying, as I know these kind of apps are checking  the app usage but what about the resources camera, wifi etc. can you explain more

Comment: Just researched through same, Unfortunately, this permission is no longer supported. [Check this for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461650/read-logs-permission-on-jelly-bean-api-16)

Comment: Thank you again, I hope I can find something that can help me, to understand users usage of these resources