# How to get logs of other apps?

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, android-log

I want to read logs from other apps and filter them so when a certain keyword is being logged, my application will perform a certain task.

I found several methods of reading logs, but from my testing I could only get my application logs.

This is the method I originally tried to use

```
try {
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

  StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
  String line = "";
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    log.append(line);
  }
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setText(log.toString());
  } 
catch (IOException e) {}
```

But it seems like it only reads the logs of my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only read the logs of all apps if the device is rooted.

If you want to read logs of rooted devices, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12642918/6570665) should help you. However, you will have to set the `targetSdk` to 16.

Comment: Do you have the code for that?
This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if you fully understand what it means to root a device. Please read [this](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-root-android/).

Comment: I know very well what a rooted device is..
It's not a problem for me to make my app root only.

I'm just asking your code to read system logs on rooted devices.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you back there. Please check edit @Rosenpin.