# Practical solution to turn on/off GPS for root Android devices (with code)

Tags: android, gps, root

There are so many topics and unanswered questions regarding possibility to turn on/off GPS from inside a custom program so I decided to publish my own research.

As known to everyone any kind of available solution uses either a hack or at very least the root access. I tested quite a few GPS on/off widgets from Google Play and no one succeeded on all of my devices. 
The proposed more or less universal solution tested for:

- Galaxy Tab 2.3.5 stock rooted,
- Motorola Atrix 4G CM10 4.1.2,
- HTC Evo 3D 4.0.2 custom rooted,
- Galaxy Note II 4.1.2 stock rooted, custom rooted and CM10.1 4.2.1,
- Galaxy S III 4.1.2 stock rooted.

Here is the short description of steps involved.

1. Create a small stub APK which does nothing except receiving a custom broadcast with parameters and updates the security strings for GPS accordingly.
2. Create a main GUI APK which included the above APK as a asset.
3. The main APK should install the stub APK into /system/app and reboot the Android. Here is the only place actually requiring the root.
4. The main APK provides additional goods like a widget, a main GUI panel, optional watchdog for Waze, Google Maps and iGo software and optional control of Bluetooth.

The full source code is here: 
http://rapidshare.com/files/1458124346/GPSToggler-20130222.7z

Please consider the above code as a sample and not like a final product. Bugs are possible,
Also remember any tampering with /system/app area may soft-brick your device.

Hard bricks are unlikely but I accept no responsibility if your device bricked.

Comment: More advanced version with system module uninstaller and not requiring BusyBox is here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7zaudXThbF8SVo2TGxfUGhjOXM/edit?usp=sharing  or here http://rapidshare.com/files/3410445141/GPSToggler-20130226.7z

Comment: Turn On/Off GPS programatically see this [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373234/toggle-gps-on-root-devices-on-android/35320092#35320092)