# GPS toggle editing AOSP

Tags: android, gps, android-source

I want to toggle GPS without going to android settings with Intents etc . for this i have already tried these methods which none of them worked  :

[How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373234/toggle-gps-on-root-devices-on-android)

[Toggle gps on root devices on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373234/toggle-gps-on-root-devices-on-android)

so as far as i understood , there is no way for doing this . What i am asking is , Is It possible to approach this editing custom rom or AOSP ? and if it is possible anyone can help OR any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything if you edit the AOSP.  But I don't think you need to go that far.  Use `Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(context.getContentResolver(), provider, true);` and write a system app and you should be able to do it.  A description of how to install your app as a system app can be found at http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-any-app-as-system-app-on-android/.  Then add the WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission to your manifest and you're good.

Comment: thank you for your answer . i already tried to make System app with titanium backup but still i get the error permission now allowed