# Android lastKnownLocation returns null

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I've got this problem I don't see anything wrong in the code but getLastKnownLocation returns null every time . any ideas ?

```
public class LocationDemo2Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(location != null)    et1.setText((int)location.getLatitude());
        else et1.setText("null");

    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLastKnownLocation()` will frequently return `null`, particularly if the location provider (e.g., GPS) has not been used recently. You only use `getLastKnownLocation()` in situations where you either do not really *need* a location (but would like to have one) or where you will use other techniques if `getLastKnownLocation()` returns `null` (e.g., request location updates).

Comment: The how do i find location ?? I can i force the OS to use the GPS or network or Wifi to find the current location

Comment: How do i programmaticaly turn on Googles location service I tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker/5305835#5305835 but its not working I need it in 2.3.3 gingebread

Comment: @user2726456: Use `requestLocationUpdates()` to request location updates.