# Location is null on device

Tags: android

I am testing my app on a real device and getting a `null` location when the GPS is on. When I test on the emulator with dummy coordinates it works fine. What is wrong?

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
listener = new MyLocationListener();
viaGps = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
viaNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if (!viaGps && !viaNetwork) {
    tracking = false;
} else {
    if (viaGps) {
        Log.d("", "gps is on");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }else if (viaNetwork) {
        Log.d("", "network is on");
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    if (location == null) {
        Log.d("", "location not fouond");
    }
```

Comment: last known location can be null, but you should get location fix in LocationListener,

Comment: Do you have a sim card in the phone?

Comment: Yes i Do have sim card in my phone

Comment: @vmerror but why is that. i mean in the emulator before giving dummy coordinates the last known location could be null and it makes sense also. but in a real device there are real coordinates available.then why my last known location is null

Comment: Answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12238356/1199267

Comment: There aren't always real coordinates available. GPS isn't always on, and you don't always have a valid GPS fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Location listener:

Follow the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

**Update:**

You can also try that easy way: [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/944070)

Comment: i already register a location listener named locationListener.

Comment: do you get through the documentation? see my update for an other implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this , it solved my problem

```
  double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
  double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

Also check your permission

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```