# How to enable Network Location provider automatically

Tags: android

I am fetching  Latitude and Longitude through network

It is giving me latitude and longitude but what if my `NETWORK LOCATION PROVIDER` is unchecked

It will never provide me the Latitude and Longitude of the current location.

What i want is, How Can I enable the `NETWORK LOCATION PROVIDER` in phone without knowing 
user that It is opened,

How can i do that?

What i have tried is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

But this will open the page in my phone to check it  i want to check AUTOMATICALLY          

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.phone", "com.android.phone.Settings");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Both answers are right: you cannot move system settings like that just from your application, by design and for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to enable the network provider location automatically as already mentioned. The correct way is to display a box and redirect the user to the settings page. You can enable GPS by using a slight hack as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker). Still I wouldn't suggest doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to enable it automatically. Network settings must be enabled manually by user only. You can show a message to the user to enable his network.

You can able to open the Location Services page to enable it. By programmatic, not possible.

Comment: No. GPS also will fall under the same category.

Comment: I can Enable GPS as mentioned below