# Automatic Testing of Geofences with Android Emulator on Travis

Tags: android, android-emulator, travis-ci, android-geofence

i'm trying to use Android Geofences in my App and test the App via Travis-CI. Everything works fine on my local device and on my local Emulator. But not on Travis-CI.

It turns out, that the Geofences couldn't be added because the network location provider is disabled. (I receive `GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error status)

Checking on my Location Settings with `Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE)` gives me `LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY`back which means Network Location Provider is disabled, but GPS and other sensors are enabled, according to the Documentation.

As far as I know enabling network Location Provider programmatically is not possible due to Security concerns. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158028/how-to-enable-network-location-provider-automatically)

If I disable mobile network location in the settings Menu on my local device and on the local emulator i can reproduce the behaviour from the Emulator on Travis-CI.

Is there a way to configure the Emulator on Travis that the mobile network location in the settings menu is enabled from beginning? Or can i add a geofence in my app somehow even if the network provider is disabled?

Here is my travis.yml

```
language: android
cache: false
sudo: false
env:
  global:
  - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=16
android:
  components:
  - build-tools-22.0.1
  - android-21
  - extra-google-google_play_services
  - extra-google-m2repository
  - extra-android-m2repository
  - addon-google_apis-google-21
  - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-addon-google_apis-google-21

before_install:
- chmod +x gradlew
- android list target
- echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21"
  --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a
- emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
- chmod +x wait_for_emulator.sh
- ./wait_for_emulator.sh
- sleep 30

before_script:

- adb logcat &
- adb shell input keyevent 82 &
- sleep 30
- adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed off &
- sleep 30
- adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed network,gps,wifi &
- sleep 30
- adb shell input keyevent 22 &
- sleep 10
- adb shell input keyevent 23
- sleep 10



script:


- "./gradlew build connectedCheck --stacktrace --continue -PdisablePreDex"
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update:**

After some research and thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109472/disabling-agreeing-to-location-consent-programmatically-android-kitkat) post i found out that i can change the settings via this `adb shell` command:

```
settings put secure location_providers_allowed network,gps,wifi
```

But still there is user consent required. I tried to accept with:

```
input keyevent 22
input keyevent 23
```

This works on my local device and my local emulator, but still fails on the Travis-Emulator. I changed the attached travis.yml accordingly and the Travis-Logfile can be found [here](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/71634677/log.txt?deansi=true). After all the network provider is still not enabled and it seems the `ConfirmAlertActivity` pops up after the Application is started for testing and not when I give the enable command via `adb`.