# Consultation about turn on and off GPS android

Tags: android

i try to turn on and off the GPS like this:

```
 private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

    private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

but i got error on **secure**  in this line:

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
```

Comment: What does "i got error" mean exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker - it says the method you try to use is based on Android bug, fixed in 2.3.

Comment: Yes, this script-kiddie hack has long since been closed. Users can enable or disable GPS through the Settings app or a device-supplied app widget.

Answer (score 0):

to give the user option to turn gps on or off use

```
final LocationManager manager = 
         (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
     new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

in earlier version there was a hack to do this from application but I am not sure whether this is possible in higher versions..

in manifest use following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: i try this, now i got error on ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS.  i dont have root on my phone, Does it belong ?