# How can I enable disable GPS programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, gps

I am creating an anti-theft application and, locating my phone through sms and it works perfectly until 2.3.
But in 4.0 I can't turn on or off gps programmatically is there any other possible way to switch on gps through code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker have look here

Comment: past  pic of code in your question .

Comment: Have you checked this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/enable-gps-programatically-like-tasker ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try using this code. It worked for me on all the versions.

```
public void turnGPSOn()
{
     Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
     intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
     this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);


    }
}
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Comment: this code turns on gps in my device and it is not working in turn off i am using 4.0.4 ics

Comment: hi it is not working in samsung galaxy y. it put gps receiver is on always on mode, after getting fix it should be on sleep mode..

Comment: try this code to turn off gps


Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");

intent.putExtra("enabled", false);

sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: For those who are facing problem with "ctx".
ctx is nothing but instance of the activity. If you declare these functions in your activity then use "className.this" instead of ctx.

Comment: Thanks..... But i think it wont work if the widget is not present.. And i guess the widget is only available on Nexus Devices,...

Comment: I am getting "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE". App is crashing

Comment: I am also getting  "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE". - Any Advice

Comment: Joolah and user1035292 you have to add the permissions to the manifest.

Comment: Not working in android M

Comment: @ Diogo Nunes-- which permission we need to add. facing same crash like 
Joolah and user1035292

Comment: you can use

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.ACCESS_GPS" />

Comment: `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED` is deprecated.

Comment: this does not work anymore since Android 4.4

Comment: Does not work anymore!