# i want to turn on the gps location automatically, without showing settings to user?

Tags: android, gps

I want to turn on the **GPS** Location enable automatically in background on click on the yes button from the dialog. how its possible?

```
Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
//                                      android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
//                              ChatSDK.getSDKInstance().activity
//                                      .startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                                String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ChatSDK.getSDKInstance().activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
                                if(provider.contains("gps")){ // for turn on
                                    final Intent poke = new Intent();
                                    System.out.println("innnnnnnnnn");
                                    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                                    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                                    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
                                    ChatSDK.getSDKInstance().activity.sendBroadcast(poke);
                                    Toast.makeText(ChatSDK.getSDKInstance().activity, "Your GPS is Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                  }

                            }
```

Comment: is it possible to turn on the gps location?

Comment: So, you want to be able to change an important privacy setting on the user's phone without them knowing?

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426144/turning-on-and-off-gps-programmatically-in-android-4-0-and-above)

Comment: @RethinavelPillai, those codes doesnt work any more.

Comment: did you check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android