# Turning On/Off GPS like in Android Settings

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I have found the answer for basic turning GPS ON/OFF.

[Turning on and off GPS programmatically in android 4.0 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426144/turning-on-and-off-gps-programmatically-in-android-4-0-and-above)

But this does not really correspond to all location setting one finds in the Settings system app.  In particular there are:

1) Use Wireless Networks
2) Use GPS Satellites
3) Location and Google Services.

The code to switch on/off refers to which of the three?  what about the other two? How can those be turned on/off programatically?

Comment: *The code to switch on/off refers to which of the three?* you can find out easily by trying the code and see what it does

Comment: If it's so simple, why don't *you* do the research and answer the question yourself? I was just giving a tip. I don't understand why you felt the need to attack me. Hostility is not appreciated here.

Comment: what are you talking about? Don't be so sensitive!

Comment: Very funny. Just remember that you are the one asking a question and it's you who depends on our help, not the other way around. I advise you to not continue with this kind of behaviour and act a little more professional here on Stack Overflow if you want help with your problems.

Comment: When you see a question and don't know the answer its always an option to just move along.