# Programmatically Turn On Gps in Android Lollipop

Tags: java, android, gps

I just want to know if there's any way to automatically turn on Gps in android JellyBean.I have tried some codes previously mentioned but none of them are working on jellybean.Thanks

Comment: How about the one mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426144/turning-on-and-off-gps-programmatically-in-android-4-0-and-above.

Comment: your title says lollipop and description says jelly bean

Comment: No, not possible.  The loopholes that allowed this previously have been closed.

Comment: I meant lollipop...sorry about the mistake