# How can I resolve "Locmanager"?

Tags: android

I have a problem with this code:

```
boolean gpsStatus = locmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (!gpsStatus) {
    Settings.Secure.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, "network,gps");
}
```

I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10004614/2628458
I tried to switch "locmanager" with "LocationManager" and it has not worked. It says: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method isProviderEnabled(String) from the type LocationManager."

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you want open gps, you can use following codes

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(!provider.contains("gps")){
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and for close gps

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(provider.contains("gps")){
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this code and i get an error: Uri cannot be resolved. What is Uri?
Anyway i would like to use a normal method, not an exploit. I have a rooted phone.

Comment: You must import the Uri. like this ;

    import android.net.Uri;

or shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+O (not zero)

Comment: And you should put that permission in your manifest file. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: I working on Android 2.3.3 and i tried 4.2.2 in my project but there is no android.net.uri or contentUri. I tried the fix project properties in the android tools but it did nothing. You have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message because you changed a reference to an object instance:

```
locManager
```

into a reference to the class:

```
LocationManager
```

References to classes are *static.*  To understand what this means, think of the class LocationManager as a cookie cutter, and objects like `locManager1` and `locManager2` as cookies that were created by that cookie cutter.

It should seem apparent that a cookie cutter cannot eat (consume) the cookies that it has created.  Similarly, Java does not allow you to refer to (or consume) a method on a cookie from a cookie cutter.

Why is this? Because cookies contain state, and cookie cutters do not.  Cookies can be green (if you put green food coloring in them).  That is a *state* of the cookie, not the cookie cutter.  You can't call a `getColor` method on a cookie cutter, *unless you first hand it a reference to the cookie.*  The cookie cutter doesn't have a color.

Read up on `static`, objects and instances.