# Disable GPS Location

Tags: android, gps

I want enable and disable GPS. I want like Google map app, when run app, the app ask from me enable my location and when my app goes to background(pause state) gps disable, I mean i don't see gps icon in top of screen, and when again app goes to foreground, again my location enable . I did not use `LocationOverlay` . I write `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);` in `onPause()` method, but when my app goes to background, i see gps on and enable and try detect my location!

I write enable location but i don't know how can disable gps and then hide gps icon!

Please help me

Thanks for advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disable GPS programmatically on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android)

```
 private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
```

To remove icon and turn off gps:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener); 
locationManager = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I write turnGPSOff() method without removerUpdates() and when app goes to background. gps turn off. what is difference between removeUpdates() and turnGPSOff() ?

Comment: and another question. I want when disable gps with second answer form  your send link, my gps disable but on, and when i goes to app again, in onResume(), how can i detect gps disable that after i enable this and if gps is turn off, i turn on gps! I detect gps on and off wtih this code : (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))

Answer (score 0):

Try those:

```
private void turnGPSOn()
{
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(!provider.contains("gps"))
{ //if gps is disabled
final Intent poke = new Intent();
poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
sendBroadcast(poke);
}
}

private void turnGPSOff()
{
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

if(provider.contains("gps"))
{ //if gps is enabled
final Intent poke = new Intent();
poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
sendBroadcast(poke);
}
}
```

**Please note** that you need to set proper app permissions.

Comment: looks off and on use same codes, so can we just use one toggle function for both on&off