# how do I automatically turn on GPS in Android

Tags: android, gps

I am creating an app in which it automaticaly turns on the gps of the phone when certain events are triggered.kindly help me with this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy reasons. While there were some hacks, like the one in answer, that used to work, those security flaws have since been fixed.

P.S This was answered by CommonsWare

Android Guidelines have changed above version 4.0. You cannot change GPS off on programmatically for versions above 4.0. However, you can change wifi off on programmatically.