# Google map is enabling GPS programmatically?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-location

I noticed that with the new update to google map, if you have GPS is off, then it warns you about the accuracy. Here is the new thing, if you hit OK then it enables the GPS for you. Which means it is programmatically enabling GPS as opposed to me going to Settings. I have Kitkat running on samsung S4

Does this means that there is an official way to enable GPS programatically?IF yes then how?

Thanks[image]

Comment: I just tried on mine and it resulted in the same conventional way of doing it by intent. Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: There used to be security bug - I guess they fixed it. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

Comment: Here is the dialog that appears, if I click on  ok then it will enable the GPS (without going to settings)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm after the new update you can turn on GPS/Location from within the Google Maps application. However haven't heard any news yet about how to use this in other apps. Probably an API in the next version of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play service 7.0 and above have this feature.

> In Google Play services 7.0, we’re introducing a standard mechanism to
>   check that the necessary location settings are enabled for a given
>   LocationRequest to succeed. If there are possible improvements, you
>   can display a one touch control for the user to change their settings
>   without leaving your app.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html