# Android gps programmatically turning on and turning off

Tags: android, gps

i have written a simple gps code , which is turning on  and turning off the gps programmatically in some device(say moto g) but some older version or Samsung duos and some other devices it not turning on gps programmatically .
please help me regarding this issue,

If  gps is turned on successfully i will get latitude and longitude, so i will use it

and thanks in advance

> You have to decrease your API level from Manifest File

Comment: Please post your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please change it as per your requirement.

Turn Of GPS

```
    private void turnGPSOn() 
{

    String provider = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (!provider.contains("gps")) 
    { 
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Stop GPS and Get Lat Long

this code for stop gps

```
LocationUtil locationUtil = new LocationUtil(getApplicationContext());
                        locationUtil.stopUsingGPS();
 if (statusOfGPS) {

         Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
         intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
         sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

     String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
     if(provider.contains("gps"))
     { //if gps is enabled
         final Intent poke = new Intent();
         poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
         poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
         poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
         sendBroadcast(poke);
     }
```

Get Lat Long

```
public class LocationUtil implements LocationListener 
{
private Context context;
private LocationManager locationManager;
Location ToPassLocation = null;
// chetan changes
private String provider;

// changes

public LocationUtil(Context context) 
{
    this.context = context;
    Log.d("Location", "Object created");

    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);
}

public Location getLatLongLast() 
{
    // chetan changes
    if (ToPassLocation == null) 
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider.isEmpty()) 
        {   
            Log.e("Location_Util", "OLD Provider:- NETWORK_Provider");
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            return location;
        }
        else if (provider.isEmpty()) 
        {
            Log.e("Location_Util", "OLD Provider:- GPS_Provider");
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            return location;
        }
        else 
        {
            Log.e("Location_Util", "OLD Provider:- PASSIVE_Provider");
            provider = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            onProviderEnabled(provider);
            return location;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log.e("Location_Util", "NEW Provider:- Will get while calling get provider");
        return ToPassLocation;
    }
} 

  //    public Location getLatLongLastNew()
 // { 
//      return ToPassLocation;
//  } 
//  

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    ToPassLocation = location;
    System.err.println("Location New:-"+ ToPassLocation);
    System.err.println("Latitude__:-"+location.getLatitude()+"-:");
    System.err.println("Longitude_:-"+location.getLongitude()+"-:");
    Log.e("Location_Util",  "Provider__:-"+location.getProvider());
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

  public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: if we on GPS using above code we have to stop it from code too that means if we want to  turn off GPS from device setting we cant do it.

Comment: **"I have give you my hole"** this made me laugh XD

Comment: Not functional on 5.1.1

Comment: Not functional on Android 6

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends if you catch the geolocation by Google Play Services or if you do it the "old" way. I would not suggest to do something behind the user. A common way is to check if the GPS is on and at best direct the user to the system settings by using a [PreferenceScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html). Also inform the user with a [DialogPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) or a toast. Otherwise if you want to do it the dirty way, you can find an answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void turnGPSOn() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if (!provider.contains("gps")) { //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
    intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);

    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if (provider.contains("gps")) { //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```