# how to get the response from location on or off in android?

Tags: java, android, android-location, locationmanager

In my app, using switch button for location on and off. How to fetch this switch button with default location option(ON or OFF) function. I am new for this ,help me any one.

Comment: Checkout this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/36173146/1640009

Comment: Is task done? ....

Comment: No but can't possible to off globally...

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- if you're using `Location Listener` then try this

---

```
//take AlertDialog globally
AlertDialog alert;
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
 {
// Here you need to call alert of enabling location to get the update 
  location
   showSettingsAlert();
  }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
 {
 alert.dismiss();
}
 public void showSettingsAlert(){
try {
        LoginActivity.isGPSAlertShown=true;
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
        alert.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alert.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                isFromSetting = true;
                LoginActivity.isGPSAlertShown=false;
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```