# how to Auto Enable GPS

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions, gps, location

Go to Settings -> Location Services-> Check on access to my location, I wanted to do this programatically autoEnable ,I tried this below code but not working

```
Intent intent=new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");      
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
private void turnGPSOn(){     
 String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);      if(!provider.contains("gps")){ 
    //if gps is disabled         
    final Intent poke = new Intent();           
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");          poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);         poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));          
    sendBroadcast(poke);     

          } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider API Version
//Enabled

---

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

//Disabled

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

---

Set Permisstion in Android Manifest

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
```

---

[More Details Please Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: Can you Change Android Manifest??

Comment: Yes i given these permissions in manifest.This code working in some mobile,but in some mobile or tabs not working

Comment: Please Consider API Verstion

Comment: Refer This URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android?rq=1