# Android - Can GPS be enabled programmatically in an Application with Device administration capabilities?

Tags: android, gps, device-admin

I am developing an Application with Device Administration capabilities. I want to know is there anyway to programmatically enable GPS and(or) network? Any help is much appreciated...

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android/) does not work anymore. It explains about ordinary app(which does not work anymore(bug fixed)), where as what i need to know is that whether it is possible to turn GPS and network ON using device administration capabilities. Like changing settings programmatically....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: Sir, i already looked through a lot of discussions(including the above(which does not work anymore)), still no luck.