# How to enable GPS using code like Jugnoo app do?

Tags: android

Here is the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=product.clicklabs.jugnoo&hl=en which is able to turn on GPS automatically. How can I do the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

Answer (score 1):

"You can't do this for security/privacy reasons, you have to forward to location preferences screen and let the user enable/disable it."

But maybe the link below can help you out.

Check this out : [How can I enable or disable the GPS programmatically on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305835/5105257)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Official Google's Settings API https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi
through which you can enable GPS on single tab like jugnoo app will do.